# Array in python just full of zeros when opened using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, python-2.7, numpy, land-classification

I'm working on the below script. What I'm trying to do is create a stats.txt file output which has the Land Cover Class ID, Fractional Coverage (of that class) and the number of pixels (of that class) in a three column .txt so that I can pass the file, along with another .tif file I've created into the next stage of my classification project.

I've muddled through a set of errors and have solved a few (see: [size-1 array problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365489/typeerror-only-size-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-earth-observa/54365664#54365664)).

My current problem is two-fold, my output file just creates a string of numbers not separated by anything so I'm not sure what that is caused by, but I've tried various methods to write to a file (as you can see below).

My main issue is that when I run the code in part, in ipython, I come across the issue that my input .tif file (a CEH landcover map product: https://eip.ceh.ac.uk/lcm/lcmdata) when read, is producing an array of just zeros and I'm not sure that is right.

```
In [3]: print lc
[[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 ...

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Below is the main bulk of the code I have thus far.

How do I fix this problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import calendar
import os

from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

from IPython import embed

GDAL2NUMPY = {  gdal.GDT_Byte      :   np.uint8,
                gdal.GDT_UInt16    :   np.uint16,
                gdal.GDT_Int16     :   np.int16,
                gdal.GDT_UInt32    :   np.uint32,
                gdal.GDT_Int32     :   np.int32,
                gdal.GDT_Float32   :   np.float32,
                gdal.GDT_Float64   :   np.float64,
                gdal.GDT_CInt16    :   np.complex64,
                gdal.GDT_CInt32    :   np.complex64,
                gdal.GDT_CFloat32  :   np.complex64,
                gdal.GDT_CFloat64  :   np.complex128
              }


#Open the training LC map file.

fname = sys.argv[1]
lc_dataset = gdal.Open(fname)
lc = lc_dataset.ReadAsArray()
#lc = np.array(lc)

#Calculating total number of pixels with a valid Land Cover ID.

fill_value = 0
number_of_pixels = np.where(lc != fill_value)[0].shape[0]

#Get the number of classes and corresponding IDs.

lc_classes = np.unique(lc)

#Split each class into its contituante pixel and write result to file.

f = open("LCM2015_stats_test.txt", "w+")

for classID in lc_classes:
    lc_class_pixels = np.where(lc == classID)[0].shape[0]
    FractionalCover = lc_class_pixels/number_of_pixels
    DAT = np.column_stack((classID, FractionalCover, lc_class_pixels))
    np.savetxt('LCM2015_stats_text_2.txt', DAT, delimiter = "", fmt="%s")
    #f.write(classID, FractionalCover, lc_class_pixels)
    break
f.close()
```

If I can provide any extra information please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, why do you think the dataset is being read as all 0's?  If you're just looking at the output of `print(lc)` then you're not seeing the whole array just snippets from the edges (3 elements from each end of each dimension by default). In the example below, I print out the array and it just shows the zeroes at each edge of the array, but then I print the max class value and the class count and it shows that there's more data in there than shown by the `print(lc)`.

Secondly, you're not supplying any delimiters when writing out the file so no delimiters get written.  The example below uses the `csv` module, but [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) has a `delimiters` argument or you could just join the values into a delimited string yourself `f.write(','.join([classID, FractionalCover, lc_class_pixels])+'\n')` etc...

```
import csv 
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

ds = gdal.OpenEx('lcm2015_ni_1km_dominant_target_class.img')
lc = ds.ReadAsArray()

fill_value = 0
number_of_pixels = np.where(lc != fill_value)[0].shape[0]

#Get the number of classes and corresponding IDs.
lc_classes = np.unique(lc)

#Split each class into its constituent pixel and write result to file.
with open("LCM2015_stats_test.csv", "w") as f:

    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['classID', 'FractionalCover', 'lc_class_pixels']) # Header

    for classID in lc_classes:
        lc_class_pixels = np.where(lc == classID)[0].shape[0]
        FractionalCover = lc_class_pixels/number_of_pixels
        DAT = np.column_stack((classID, FractionalCover, lc_class_pixels))
        #np.savetxt('LCM2015_stats_text_2.txt', DAT, delimiter = "", fmt="%s")
        writer.writerow([classID, FractionalCover, lc_class_pixels])

print('array:\n', lc, '\n')
print('max:', lc.max(), '\n')
print('number_of_pixels:\n', number_of_pixels, '\n')
print('lc_classes:', lc_classes, '\n')

!cat LCM2015_stats_test.csv  # The "!" is IPython syntax to run a shell command, doesn't work in standard python interpreter/scripts

array:
 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]] 

max: 21 

number_of_pixels:
 14865 

lc_classes: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 20 21] 

classID,FractionalCover,lc_class_pixels
0,1.0450723175243861,15535
1,0.007198116380760175,107
2,0.04803229061553986,714
3,0.036057854019508916,536
4,0.6708375378405651,9972
5,0.007332660612176253,109
6,6.727211570803902e-05,1
7,0.02536158762193071,377
9,0.010023545240497814,149
10,0.03477968382105617,517
11,0.057315842583249246,852
12,6.727211570803902e-05,1
13,0.015472586612848975,230
14,0.041439623276152034,616
15,0.0003363605785401951,5
16,0.003363605785401951,50
17,0.0013454423141607804,20
18,0.006054490413723511,90
20,0.003901782711066263,58
21,0.031012445341405986,461
```